dbt custom schema vs default schema
I’m using dbt core 1.4 with a multi-schema structure where tables are grouped into different folders, and each folder should insert tables into a specific schema.
I’ve set the default schema to dbo in my profiles.yml, and defined different schemas for each folder in dbt_project.yml. However, when I run a model that should be created in a new schema, I encounter the following error:
relation <default_schema>.<model_name> does not exist.

It seems like dbt is still searching for the table in the default schema (dbo), even though the new table should be created in the schema defined for its folder.
My Setup:

profiles.yml: Default schema set to dbo.
dbt_project.yml: Schemas are defined per folder using +schema.

Question:
Why might dbt be searching for the table in the default schema instead of the folder-specific schema? What steps should I take to ensure dbt properly resolves schemas based on the folder structure and not choose default schema?
tried --no-partial-parse 
generate_schema_name
generate_schema_name_env


Have you checked the dbt_project.yml to check if the schema/folders are configured correctly?
